# geoserver layer access through postgis accounts logins

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a postgis geographical database with different access accounts.
how do i set a layer in geoserver so that the wfs insert, update, delete transactions  can only be done through these accounts and logins in my web interface (openlayers) ?